# Dataflow: Stream pub/sub messages from different project

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, publish-subscribe

I have a pub/sub topic in project A. I would now like to stream messages from that topic into a dataflow pipeline running in a different project B. I have followed the example at https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/stream-messages-dataflow and everything works when the topic is in the same project as the dataflow pipeline. However, when trying to stream messages from a topic in a different project I get the following permissions error:

```
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2022-11-09T16:34:40.349Z: JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR: Workflow failed. Causes: Check if topic projects/XXXXXXX/topics/test-topic exists failed with error: User not authorized to perform this action.
```

The service account which runs the pipeline has the Pub/Sub Admin role in both projects. I even tried making it Owner in project A (where the topic lives), but no success. I always get the same error.

Comment: A common troubleshooting this error is checking the project IDs of both project. It usually has a wrong project ID from the source or target project when receiving this error.  Can you check if the project ids in your pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to create a subscription in the source project (A), so your dataflow job (in the project B) takes the messages from that subscription (from the project A).

Then yoou find out a service account under which your dataflow job is runnig (in the project B). Presumably that service account is in the project B. And provide relevant permissions to that service account, so it can work with the source subscription (from the project A).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue :

- Run the `Dataflow` job in the project B
- The service account is created for example in the project B
- In the `IAM` menu of projet A, give the permissions to read from the `Pub Sub` in the projet A
- In the `IAM` menu of projet B, give the permissions to launch a `Dataflow` job in the project B
- When you launch your `Dataflow` job in the project B, set a program argument indicating what [Service Account email](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#python) launches the job :

For `Dataflow` `Python` :

```
--service_account_email=my-service-account-name@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

For `Dataflow` `Java` :

```
--serviceAccount=my-service-account-name@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: @MartinWiebusch have you solved your issue ?